# Is it possible to find out what class an edges source and/or target has?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have given some nodes a class "hidden" and some a class "visible".

I am using the

```
d3.selectAll(".link")
```

to select all links in my force directed graph. These links have both source and target, all linked in a JSON file.

I want to go through these links and check the links source node class (and the target) and see if any of the classes = visible/hidden.

If both the source and target are "visible" then the link will have a "visible" class else have a "hidden" class.

How do I see what the links source and target classes are ?

Here is what I have tried but I do not know what to put in the main 'if' statement.

```
  d3.selectAll(".link.visible").attr("class", function(d) {
        var c = "link";
        if (d.source.visible && d.target.visible) //here this doesnt work, I need to
        //find out if source and target of the selected link are visible
        { 
            clog("VISIBLE");
            c += " visible";
        } else {
            clog("HIDDEN");
            c += " hidden";
        }
        return c;
  });
```

Where I apply the visible class to all nodes at the start :

```
var nodes = inner.selectAll(".node").append("g")
    .data(network.network.data.nodes)

nodes.classed("visible", true);
```

Here is where I show/hide nodes depending if they're selected or not

```
nodes.classed("hidden", function (d)
    {
        //if()
        return d.selected ? false : true;
    });

    nodes.classed("visible", function (d)
    {
        return d.selected ? true : false;
    });
```

Comment: How are you setting the visibility of the node initially?

Comment: visible nodes have a class .visible where visibility:visible - and hidden nodes have a class .hidden where visibility:hidden. I think that is what you meant ? @couchand

Comment: No, I'm asking where you apply those classes.  If you have a property on the node data that you're using to determine which class gets applied to the DOM element, just use that same data property.

Comment: i am not too sure I understand you. I apply the visible class at the start (edited my question). I am able to select nodes by using a brush and when I click a button it keeps all selected in view and hides the unselected (gives "hidden" class) like in the updated question.

Comment: As an aside, your code would be simpler if you just used `!` and `!!` instead of returning boolean literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `source` and `target` data nodes both have a property `selected` that determines the visibility of the associated DOM node, just use that property instead of looking for the CSS classes.

```
d3.selectAll(".link")
    .attr("class", function(d) {
        return d.source.selected && d.target.selected ? "visible" : "hidden";
    });
```

Comment: It may be that the code as written removes the `link` CSS class from the edges.  It probably should be modified to use `classed` instead of `attr`.  I would set up your CSS classes so you only need to apply one of them (probably `hidden`) and just assume that they're visible otherwise.

Comment: forget I said that last bit. With a mess around with what you gave me, it finally works. I didn't think about just using the DOM property. Works perfectly :) Thank you

Comment: also, I use two classes, visible and hidden so it's alot easier to select them. Its easier to say selectAll("visible") rather than selectAll(!"hidden"). :) Just my opinion

Comment: That's not really the D3 way.  It's Data Driven Documents.  Rely on the data, don't rely on the state of the DOM.

Comment: Yeah I suppose. I'm kinda new in all this so still a lot of learning to do as you can tell. Appreciate the help :)